# How to consume application/xml in UmbracoApiController?

Tags: api, umbraco

I am trying to create a controller action that could respond to a webhook that sends application/xml. However I get **`415 Unsupported Media Type`** error when trying to access it via Postman.

```
[PluginController("MyPlugin")]
public class MyPluginServiceController : UmbracoApiController
{ ...
    [HttpPost]
    [Consumes("application/xml")]
    public IActionResult HandleXml([FromBody] XElement body)
    {
        return Content(body.ToString());
    }

}
```

I've also configured services to **AddXmlSerializerFormatters**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddMvc().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();

        services
                .AddUmbraco(_env, _config)
                .AddBackOffice()
                .AddWebsite()
                .AddComposers()
                .Build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should tell your controller to accept xml.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()
        .AddXmlSerializerFormatters(); 
}
```